# Failed to curl in python but okay in bash. (ubuntu)

Tags: python, bash, curl

```
curl -sd '{"inputs":[{"addresses": ["Ee6B32dD1Ca58560831393404891bFDe2fb2efb0"]}],"outputs":[{"addresses": ["a1732BfA2574aEdE9867074131CA1116881fBD5e"], "value":    10000}]}' https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/txs/new?token=a893cd1d9d8a4b7284be33376cdcf742
```

above curl command runs fine in ubuntu bash shell.

But it failed as python with below code.

```
import requests
url     = 'https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/txs/new?token=a893cd1d9d8a4b7284be33376cdcf742'

payload = {
    "inputs":{ 
            "addresses": "Ee6B32dD1Ca58560831393404891bFDe2fb2efb0"
    },
    "outputs":{
            "addresses": "a1732BfA2574aEdE9867074131CA1116881fBD5e", 
            "value":    10000
    }
}


headers = {}
res = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(res)
```

result is below.

```
<Response [400]>
```

I searched the answer a day but I couldn't find the answer.
I tried many ways like pycurl but result was same 400 error.

====================

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/txs/new?token=a893cd1d9d8a4b7284be33376cdcf742'

payload = {
    "inputs": {
        "addresses": "Ee6B32dD1Ca58560831393404891bFDe2fb2efb0"
    },
    "outputs": {
        "addresses": "a1732BfA2574aEdE9867074131CA1116881fBD5e",
        "value": 10000
    }
}

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
res = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
print(res)
```

still gives 400 err...

Comment: Your curl command posts *JSON*, your Python code posts form data.

Comment: I check the previous page tried but result was same.  headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'} .   res = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

Comment: your data structure also doesn't match what curl posts. Both inputs and outputs are lists of objects.

Comment: Since I chaged payload as {"inputs":[{"addresses": ["Ee6B32dD1Ca58560831393404891bFDe2fb2efb0"]}],"outputs":[{"addresses": ["a1732BfA2574aEdE9867074131CA1116881fBD5e"], "value":    10000}]} .    it works fine. it was json header and json data format matter. Thank you.